# Can every polynomial be seen as characteristic polynomial of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we have a polynomial in a single indeterminate $x$
$$
a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dotsb + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0,
$$
can we always find a matrix for which this polynomial is a characteristic polynomial? Or are there polynomials which cannot be characteristic polynomials to any matrix?

Comment: Look up [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).